# Facebook login button on Android causing ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Facebook's Android SDK. If I add Facebook's LoginButton to my xml layout. I receive a runtime error: `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.dupls.wedding.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: null
            at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
            at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:735)
            at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.dupls.wedding.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dupls.wedding"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any determine what the cause of this Exception is. I can instantiate the Facebook SDK objects, I just can't seem to add a LoginButton to my UI. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: post your main activity

Answer (score 23):

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceSate) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
    **FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());**
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
}
```

Initialize `FacebookSdk` before `setContentView` in your class.

Comment: I got the same problem and that works! FacebookSdk init have to be placed before setContentView method

Comment: Initialize that code correctly. the code want to set above the setcontentview

Answer (score 2):

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
```

put this line before the setContentView

Answer (score 1):

Check the sizes of the libraries in the place you built and the path you copied to.Sometimes when the library is partially copied,this error occurs.

Comment: I have a feeling this is the underlying issue. I am not entirely sure how to add libraries in the new Android Studio v1.2. I went to Project Structure > Dependencies > added com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same issue. I fixed it by adding the meta-data to the manifest and the FacebookActivity as described in the following link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#login_share

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you follow all the pre-requisite steps outlined in this Facebook documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

And then add
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this)
before setContentView

Answer (score 0):

Remove mavenCentral() from repositories node in build.gradle (Project) and add it in build.gradle (Module: app) like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ehapi.rentapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```